# Holomorphic functions and primitives

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read that if $U $ is an open set and $f $ is holomorphic on $U $ then:

$f $ has locally a primitive on $U $.

But I can not understand what is meant by locally.

Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Well. For any point there exists a ball, and in that ball there is a primitive.

Comment: Okay thank you, then I understand that there is no unique primitive on the whole set U

Comment: When we say locally, we usually mean, with respect to a certain neighborhood of a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that, for each $z_0$ in the domain of $f$, there is a neighboroohd $V$ of $z_0$ contained in the domain of $f$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $V$ has a primitive. Take $\varepsilon>0$ such that $D(z_0,\varepsilon)$ is contained in the domain of $f$. Then define$$\begin{array}{rccc}F\colon&D(z_0,\varepsilon)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\displaystyle\int_0^1f\bigl(z_0+t(z-z_0)\bigr)(z-z_0)\,\mathrm dt\end{array}$$and $F$ will be a primitive of $f|_{D(z_0,\varepsilon)}$.